# Connecting an SKLabelNode to a game over SKScene label text

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, sklabelnode

I have an SKLabelNode that increments by one point every time my player touches an object:

```
let scoreLabel = childNodeWithName("points") as! Points
scoreLabel.increment()
```

However, I have an SKScene that pops up when my player hits an enemy. In the SKScene, I have labels set up for "High score", regular scoring and a tap to play again:

```
score.text = String(format: "%d", pointsLabel)
highScore.text = String(format: "%d", pointsLabel) //more of this code is in my GameScene
```

How do I connect the points label and highscore label with the pointsLabel() SKLabelNode to make the score and high score show up in my SKScene? Will post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share the `score` among several scenes you can save the value with `NSUserDefaults`.

### Saving

```
let score = 123
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "score")
```

### Reading

```
let score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("score")
```

Comment: Okay, thank you(: where would I put this in my code?

Comment: Each time you update the `score`, save a copy of it on `NSUserDefaults`. This way when you read that value from another scene you get the updated score. Please consider that value stored in `NSUserDefaults` will be available also after an app restart.